# Unable to Carry out Inner Join with pyspark.sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Please let me know if I'm in the wrong forum for the following question.

I have created the following pyspark.sql query.

```
#%%
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/packt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ops').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('/home/packt/Downloads/Spark_DataFrames/Person_Person.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
df = spark.read.csv('/home/packt/Downloads/Spark_DataFrames/Person_Password.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('Person_Person')
df.createOrReplaceTempView('Person_Password')
myresults = spark.sql("""SELECT
FirstName,
LastName,
PasswordHash
FROM Person_Person
INNER JOIN Person_Password
ON BusinessEntityID = BusinessEntityID""")
myresults.show()
```

The spark.sql query attempts to carryout a simple Inner Join. However, it keeps on failing with the following error:

```
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-0f640112ef53> in <module>()
     14 FROM Person_Person
     15 INNER JOIN Person_Password
---> 16 ON BusinessEntityID = BusinessEntityID""")
     17 myresults.show()

~/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    539         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    540         """
--> 541         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    542 
    543     @since(2.0)

~/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: "Reference 'BusinessEntityID' is ambiguous, could be: BusinessEntityID#639, BusinessEntityID#657.; line 7 pos 3"
```

Can someone please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn't know what table `BusinessEntityID` is coming from as you have your code written now.  You have to specify the table each of the columns is coming from like this:

```
ON Person_Person.BusinessEntityID = Person_Password.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: thanks for reaching out. I fixed the problem by assigning alias's to the tables